# fetch request http no envía parámetro por POST - React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, http-post

Tengo el siguiente recurso desarrollado en PHP la cual espera el parámetro `ciudad` por el método `POST`:

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

    class ObtenerLugaresTuristicos {

        private $ciudad;

        public function __construct() {

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                if (isset($_POST['ciudad'])) {
                    if (empty($_POST['ciudad'])) {
                        http_response_code(500);
                    } else {
                        $this->ciudad = htmlentities($_POST['ciudad']);

                        $this->obtenerLugaresTuristicos($this->ciudad);
                    }
                } else {
                    http_response_code(500);
                }
            } else {
                http_response_code(500);
            }
        }

        private function obtenerLugaresTuristicos($ciudad) {
            $connection = OpenConnection();

            $stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM lugares_turisticos WHERE ciudad = ? AND estado = 1');
            $stmt->execute([$this->ciudad]);

            $lugares_turisticos = array();

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $codigo_lugar_turistico = $row['codigo_lugar_turistico'];
                $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
                $foto = $row['foto'];
                $estado = $row['estado'];

                $lugar_turistico = array("codigo_lugar_turistico" => $codigo_lugar_turistico, "ciudad" => $this->ciudad, "nombre" => $nombre, "descripcion" => $descripcion, "foto"=> $foto, "estado" => $estado);
                array_push($lugares_turisticos, $lugar_turistico);
            }
            $connection == null;
            echo (json_encode($lugares_turisticos));
        }
    }

    $obtener_lugares_turisticos = new ObtenerLugaresTuristicos();
```

Y en el lado del cliente estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'

export default function Beni() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ ciudad: 'Beni', }),
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('http://192.168.1.4/lugares_turisticos/obtener_lugares_turisticos.php', requestOptions)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
  });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  });

  return (
    <View>
      {
        isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <Text>Listo</Text>
        )
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Al momento de hacer correr me devuelve la respuesta de estado `500`, y cuando modifico el `http_response_code(500)` de la línea 20 por `http_response_code(200)` ahí ya no devuelve error `500`, entonces eso significa que el parámetro `ciudad` no está llegando. Ya revise varias páginas donde indican como implementar solicitudes http con `fetch` por el método `POST` y ninguno me funciona.